# How to Import SVG icons in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, import

I wanted to import too many SVG icons in app & each icons required custom color through css, which is the easiest way to import to react?
Importing to `<img/>` tag won't support the color change via css fill.
Creating a .js component for each icon is too hard for 250+ icons.
what is the other option ? Please help

```
import IconArrow from "./Arrow.svg";
import Circlearrowdownright from "./Arrow.js";

<img className="ico" src={IconArrow} />
<i className="ico"><Circlearrowdownright /></i>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/svg-icon-3z0qu6

Comment: Just use the `svg` directly.

Comment: You mean <svg code ? Instead of <img> tag or <Circlearrowdownright /> ?

Comment: I don't know exactly how to do it in react, but in the browser it should just render the SVG inline: `<p class="some-other-markup"> <svg><path>.... </svg> </p>` something like that inside a `<p>` tag as an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import and use it as React component directly:

```
import { ReactComponent as ExampleIcon} from './icons/ExampleIcon.svg';

<ExampleIcon className="css-class"/>
```

Comment: does this work on all React Apps or just when you use Create React App?

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically import SVG & render on the fly ([CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/svg-icon-forked-scq3zx)). No need to create a separate `.js` component for every SVG file.

The `hook`

```
function useDynamicSVGImport(name, options = {}) {
  const ImportedIconRef = useRef();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState();

  const { onCompleted, onError } = options;
  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    const importIcon = async () => {
      try {
        ImportedIconRef.current = (
          await import(`./${name}.svg`)
        ).ReactComponent;
        if (onCompleted) {
          onCompleted(name, ImportedIconRef.current);
        }
      } catch (err) {
        if (onError) {
          onError(err);
        }
        setError(err);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };
    importIcon();
  }, [name, onCompleted, onError]);

  return { error, loading, SvgIcon: ImportedIconRef.current };
}
```

`Icon` component that uses the hook

```
/**
 * Simple wrapper for dynamic SVG import hook. You can implement your own wrapper,
 * or even use the hook directly in your components.
 */
export const Icon = ({ name, onCompleted, onError, ...rest }) => {
  const { error, loading, SvgIcon } = useDynamicSVGImport(name, {
    onCompleted,
    onError
  });
  if (error) {
    return error.message;
  }
  if (loading) {
    return "Loading...";
  }
  if (SvgIcon) {
    return <SvgIcon {...rest} />;
  }
  return null;
};
```

Usage

```
return (
    <>
      <Icon
        name="Arrow"
        fill="gray"
        width="100"
        onCompleted={handleOnCompleted}
        onError={handleIconError}
      />
      <Icon
        name="delete"
        fill="gray"
        width="50"
        onCompleted={handleOnCompleted}
        onError={handleIconError}
      />
    </>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

React works fine with native Web Components. Only when you want to interact with them using Events or pass Data is where React (still) fails to support the standard: https://custom-elements-everywhere.com/

- Creating a `<svg-icon>` tag is only a few lines of code.
- Added a `replaceWith` attribute so the `<svg>` you load replaces the `<svg-icon>`, makes it easier to work with global CSS.
- Added a `shadowRoot` attribute to **move** any content TO shadowDOM

```js
customElements.define("svg-icon", class extends HTMLElement {
  async connectedCallback(
    src = this.getAttribute("src"),
    shadowRoot = this.shadowRoot || this.attachShadow({mode:"open"})
  ) {
    shadowRoot.innerHTML = await (await fetch(src)).text()
    shadowRoot.append(...this.querySelectorAll("[shadowRoot]"))
    this.hasAttribute("replaceWith") && this.replaceWith(...shadowRoot.childNodes)
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid: 1fr/1fr 5fr;
}

path {
  stroke: green;
  stroke-width: .2;
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<svg-icon replaceWith src="https://svg-cdn.github.io/bi-arrows.svg"></svg-icon>
<svg-icon src="https://svg-cdn.github.io/simple-worldmap.svg">
  <style shadowRoot>
    path {
      fill: orange
    }
  </style>
</svg-icon>
```